# Launch Synergy on boot

Tags: boot, synergy

How can I have Synergy client on Windows launch on boot?  Updated to 1.4.2. but didn't see any new menu option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to go to the "Edit" menu and select "Services".

That opens this window:

[image]

Clicking "Install" under "Client" will install the synergy client service which starts up when the computer boots.

If you get a message about not having permission to install the service then you need to run Synergy as Administrator.

Answer (score 3):

Drag a shortcut into the folder called "Startup" in the start menu.

Comment: This usually won't work for Synergy as it often needs to start earlier in the boot process (e.g. before login.)  This method also runs it as the logged in user, while Synergy works best running with elevated privileges (which you get when running it as a service.)