# Synergy Client 1.4.12 as a boot-time service in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, synergy

I'm trying to configure a Synergy client using the latest version on my Windows XP machine to allow me to log in using the keyboard on the server (which is Linux but that is beside the point).  The newer Synergy configuration applications don't seem to come with the same Windows Services dialog as shown in [this superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/271370/launch-synergy-on-boot).  In the `Edit->Settings` dialog, the `Process mode` is set to `Service`, and when I look in the Windows Services, I see that there is a `Synergy` service listed that is started.

However, Ctrl+Alt+Delete doesn't seem to work, and I can't control it when the computer is locked or at the login screen.

I had this working before (with maybe an older client) but I had to rebuild my machine and can't seem to get it working again.  Most of the documentation Google sends back are for older versions of Synergy or the server side.  Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a bug in the more recent versions of Synergy that has not been fixed yet.  Reverting to Synergy 1.4.9 fixes this issue.

This bug is documented in a bug report here:
http://synergy-foss.org/spit/issues/details/3321/

After downgrading my client on Windows XP, I am able to use synergy to control the client no mater what mode it is in.